# Freelancing Path

Tags: windows, web-development-server

This is not a coding question, I am lost on what to follow for my career as a freelancer.
I have the knowledge in Software development and Web development. I don't know which one to focus on.

I have never worked in a pure development environment. I never worked in a team although I want to.

Can anyone tell me what they think? I hope I am asking in the right platform.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because "This is not a coding question"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your question is probably better adressed on StackExchange.

My opinion however: Today the boundaries between these two fields are becoming increasingly blurry. If you like both, go with Webdev and dig into backend topics. You'll find yourself on the application side of things sooner rather than later.

HTH